# Why is Haskell reading the next line as an argument for the previous function?

Tags: haskell, parameters, arguments

I am trying to run this extremely simple test program because I was having too many argument errors (reading the next line as an argument) in the code I was working with before.

When I run this code:

```
main = do{
    putStrLn ("test")
    print ("works")
}
```

I get the message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0 -> IO ()) -> [Char] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘IO ()’
    • The function ‘putStrLn’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘String -> IO ()’ has only one
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn ("test") print ("works")
      In the expression: do putStrLn ("test") print ("works")
    • Relevant bindings include main :: t (bound at test.hs:1:1)
```

Am I missing something extremely simple here?

Comment: Either remove the braces, or put a semicolon after the first line.

Comment: Expanding on that: The [layout rule](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html#layout) adds semicolons after each line (roughly speaking), but using a brace turns off the layout rule.

Comment: `do` blocks can either be written using indentation, or using braces and semicolons. In the latter case spaces/newlines no longer matter, as in C or Java. E.g. `do { something1; something2 }` is equivalent to putting the two entries on two separate, indented lines.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, there's two ways of writing block in Haskell. One uses whitespace to implicitly delineate the beginning and ending of the block and to separate parts; the other uses explicit markers. Here's how they both look:

```
-- implicit
do
    part one of block
    part two of block
      more indentend and so still part two of block
    part three of block
  less indented and so block has ended

-- explicit
do {
    part one of block;
      part two of block;
  part three of block; part four of block } block has ended
```

It turns out that the way this is specified lets you mix and match a little bit. Including semicolons to separate parts of the block is allowed in implicit mode:

```
do
    part one of block; part two of block
    part three of block
```

But mixing the other way, using curly braces to mark the beginning and end of the block but whitespace to separate parts, is not allowed.

Consequently, when you write:

```
main = do{
    putStrLn ("test")
    print ("works")
}
```

This is equivalent to one of the following:

```
-- explicit -- note, no semicolons!
main = do { putStrLn ("test") print ("works") }

-- implicit*
main = do
    putStrLn ("test") print ("works")
```

That is, this is the application of `putStrLn` to three arguments, `("test")`, `print`, and `("works")`. You can fix it either by adding a semicolon after `putStrLn ("test")` or by deleting the curly braces.

```
-- explicit
main = do{
    putStrLn ("test");
    print ("works")
}

-- implicit
main = do
    putStrLn ("test")
    print ("works")
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I suspect some experts will be thinking it odd that I put the block on the next line for the implicit version but not the explicit one. For pedagogy and parallelism with the earlier sections, I have written the first line of the block on a separate line. But yes, this is also equivalent to `main = do putStrLn ("test") print ("works")` all on one line -- and countless other variations on the theme.